# How to read byte string of JSON into pandas

Tags: python, json, pandas

I have a python byte string, that I want to read into pandas. The filetype is NDJSON (newline delimited json) which pandas reads as completely invalid.

```
s = b'{"id": "01", "amount_usd": 16.44, "foo": 1462075200.0, "bar": 1462075200.0, "baz": "abc"}\n
{"id": "02", "amount_usd": 2.88, "foo": 1462075200.0, "bar": 1462075200.0, "sample": "def"}\n
...
```

I have tried decoding it and reading it into pandas like so:

```
s = s.decode("utf-8")
pd.read_json(s)
```

But this doesn't work because the JSON structure is not what pandas expects.

I get the error

```
ERROR - Trailing data
```

How can I read this structure into pandas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's true, that's not valid JSON. If they truly are separated by newlines, you can do

```
s = '[' + ','.join(s.rstrip().split('\n')) + ']'
```

to turn it into a list.

Comment: Brilliant, that worked followed by reading it in with read_json(), thank you

Comment: Yes, after that change the string will be valid JSON.